# What is the difference between "shot full of hormones" and "full of hormones"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the 2011 movie *Carnage*,  Christoph Waltz said:

> The women we like are sensual, crazy and shot full of hormones.

What does *shot* here mean? Can we do away with it and just say *full of hormones* without mentioning *shot*?

Comment: But are there any differences? Why not just use "full of hormones"? What does "shot" mean here? An adjective?

Answer (score 5):

It's an emphasis & [humorous] comparison - an odd one if you're not accustomed to it, but it suggests that their behaviour is equivalent to them having been injected with hormones.

shot = medical injection, US Eng. Meaning 11 from [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shot_1)

It doesn't in any way imply that this is actually true, just that the effect on them is the same.